# Ruby: Delete all S3 objects with prefix using one request

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently do this to delete S3 objects in a folder / with a prefix:

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket('my-bucket')
bucket.objects(prefix: 'uploads/').map(&:delete)
```

This is probably slow for thousands of objects. I would prefer something like this to delete with one request:

```
bucket.delete(prefix: 'uploads/')
```

I can't find anything like that in the docs. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Have you tried `bucket.objects(prefix: 'uploads/').delete` ? It seems there's a Batch operation that works on collections (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Resources/Batch.html)

Comment: I get `DEPRECATION WARNING: called deprecated method 'delete' of an Aws::S3::ObjectSummary::Collection, use batch_delete!` but looks like thats essentially it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can delete **at most** 1000 objects in a **single request**. See [this API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html).

If you want to delete more than 1000 objects, you will have to issue more than 1 request.

There is no API call that allows you to delete **all** objects whose keys share a common prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define a rule under [Object Lifecycle Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) that says to expire (delete) objects in a given path (prefix) older than a certain number of days (eg one day).

This operation will automatically delete the files for **no charge** (whereas API calls to delete objects incur a charge). However, it might take 24 hours for the files to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am deleting all my objects from S3, or actually DreamObjects, a S3 compliant service from Dreamhost.

```rb
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
if DREAMHOST
  Aws.config.update(
    {s3: {endpoint: 'https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io'}}
  )
end
ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'xyz'
ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = '123'
bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
bucket.objects(prefix: 'path/to/folder/').batch_delete!
```

The API Doc I found that help do this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/ObjectSummary.html

Doc only mentions `#delete` but I got this deprecation warning...

```
#################### DEPRECATION WARNING ####################
Called deprecated method `delete` of Aws::S3::ObjectSummary::Collection. Use `batch_delete!` instead.

#############################################################
```

This is with version

```
> Aws::S3::GEM_VERSION
=> "1.136.0"
```